# Accessing select count(*) query result

Tags: java, t-sql, jpa

At the moment I don't have particular code I was strugling with today but I have problem with getting result from JPA Query.
I have something like this:

```
queryStart = \
    DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE (id int) \
    INSERT INTO @tmpTable(id) \
    SELECT id FROM myTable \
    WHERE ... \

queryEnd = \ 
    SELECT count(*) FROM @tmpTable \

String queryString = this.getResources().getString(queryStart) + I add here couple conditions to WHERE statement + this.getResources().getString(queryEnd);

Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);
```

I tried query.getResultList() but I had no luck with accessing expected output. Currently it's impossible to debug this line and try to figure out how to access my result so maybe someone could give me a hint how to save my count(*) to Integer variable.

Comment: Check adding alias for count(*) , I am not much sure about JPA though..

Comment: Note sure if you are using JPA, why would you fire an insert query when jpa facilitates the ORM to persist/modify/delete via the entity manager using its persist()/merge() or delete(). Also i could understand if this is a procedure and you want to execute a procedure from JPA